# Why does MediaStore.getMediaUri() return an empty cursor?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, uri, storage-access-framework

I'm currently making a transition to the Scoped Storage environment.
When I first saw the `MediaStore.getDocumentUri()` and `getMediaUri()`, it seemed very useful.
But after a few tests, it turned out it's completely useless.

Tell me if I'm wrong, but to me, `MediaStore.getDocumentUri()` seems like it only takes **URI**s that are originally obtained via **SAF**. That means it can only convert the **URI**s back that were previously converted using `MediaStore.getMediaUri()`.
Otherwise, I get `SecurityException` even though the file is created using *MediaStore API* and still owned by me. (Not the `RecoverableSecurityException`)

Now to the *main question*.

(The above isn't really a question. I was just complaining and hoping someone would correct me if I was wrong about it.)

Is it normal the below code always prints **"Cursor Count: 0"**?

I'm testing this for hours, but all the results are the same. If it's always empty, what's the purpose of `getMediaUri()` in the first place? (On the other hand, the original **docUri** returns a cursor with `DISPLAY_NAME` and `SIZE` in it.)

```
// docUri here is the URI returned by the system picker of SAF.
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.getMediaUri(this, docUri), null, null, null, null, null);
Log.i("my_log", "Cursor Count: " + cursor.getCount());
```

Comment: `MediaStore.getDocumentUri() seems like it only takes URIs that are originally obtained via SAF.` No. It takes an uri obtained from the mediastore.

Comment: `That means it can only convert the URIs back that were previously converted using MediaStore.getMediaUri().` No. Just use a n uri you obtained from the media store with a .query() or .insert().

Comment: @blackapps As said above, I get `SecurityException` when I do that. Also, I saw your comment saying the same thing to another poster, but they answered they got `SecurityException` too just like me. The document on `getDocumentUri()` : "callers must already hold permissions obtained with Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs.".

Comment: @blackapps If I got a media URI through *MediaStore API* at runtime, that means I already have read permission on it. It's because *MediaStore API* never returns other apps' URIs without `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the first place. So throwing the `SecurityException` exception doesn't make sense, if `getDocumentUri()` really does support pure media URIs. We get `RecoverableSecurityException` only when we try to modify/delete other apps' files, but in this case, I'm just trying to convert.

Comment: Sorry i lost where this is about. You posted two code lines. And used MediaStore.getMediaUri() for a SAF uri i understood. You then have the SAF permission. And probably you need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for querying the mediastore. But then you should get a media uri.

Comment: @blackapps Please read my last comment. I have a media URI already. So talking about `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is unnecessary here.

Comment: `The document on getDocumentUri() : "callers must already hold permissions obtained with Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs."` Aha. That is something different. That makes sense. But your code is not about this function call. And if you post is then all your writing with true and negating true made me confused. Sorry.

Comment: @blackapps I already gave up on `getDocumentUri()`. I was just complaining about it, and you wanted to talk about it so I answered. In fact, I hoped I was wrong and you were right when I first commented :(